# Neither user 10022 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS

Tags: android, kotlin, android-permissions, telecom-manager

Why this code snippet need READ_PHONE_NUMBERS permission?

```
 val manager = getSystemService(Context.TELECOM_SERVICE) as TelecomManager
        val connectionServiceId = getConnectionServiceId()
        val componentName =
            ComponentName(applicationContext, PhoneConnectionService::class.java)
        val phoneAccountHandle = PhoneAccountHandle(componentName, connectionServiceId)
```

here it causes the error.

```
phoneAccount = manager.getPhoneAccount(phoneAccountHandle)
```

> Requires Permission: Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS for
> applications targeting API level 31+.

but i am not accessing the phone from device I just created that manually like this.

```
val builder = PhoneAccount.builder(
                phoneAccountHandle,
                this.resources.getText(R.string.app_name)
            )
            val uri = Uri.parse("tel:1236547")
            builder.setSubscriptionAddress(uri)
            builder.setAddress(uri)
            builder.setCapabilities(PhoneAccount.CAPABILITY_CALL_PROVIDER)
            phoneAccount = builder.build()
            manager.registerPhoneAccount(phoneAccount)
```

**So how can use this code or do this same process without READ_PHONE_NUMBERS permission?**

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

I just removed this line because it is not much needed.

> phoneAccount = manager.getPhoneAccount(phoneAccountHandle)

Without this line, the code works properly without any permission.

Comment: Whats was your use case @Mohammad Taqi? Display the Android call screen, triggered from an external service/application?

Comment: Actually I am using ConnectionService service.
My requirements are = When a notification appears I need to create a incoming call for AGORA CALING.
that's I uses Connection service to create(handle) the incoming call.
(Hope I make you understand ;) )

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Mohammad Taqi.
How did you solve it without "getting a phone account"? In order to use the standard Android Calling UI I believe you need to register a phone account, which means that the user must select your app as a calling app?
I've been using CAPABILITY_CALL_PROVIDER for a long time and that has been enough, but something happened lately which has resulted in error messages such as "phone account not enabled for user" and "neither user has android permissions". Trying to get back on track without the need a being a default calling app.

Comment: No, I don't use standard calling UI; instead, I create my own.
I only require this solution to manage my calls in an organized way.
I use for agora calling along with my custom UI and ConnectionService.

Comment: Thanks!
Created a custom now. Ideally I'd want the system to just throw up the standard ringing behaviour like we had it before but in later Android APIs its become more complex with permissions and enabled phone accounts etc.
We now use Firebase push to trigger connection service incoming call, which triggers a notification push with high importance, that includes actions to answer or decline, along with a custom call screen for when your in the app.